# Enable Inline Editing for Lightning Table

Tags: datatable, lightning-components

I have a LWC Table that is in a custom object and will need to display in the Record Page similar to a Table in Excel.
The goal is to be able to enter Quantity and the other columns will not take user input, it will always display static values.
I have been able to successfully display the table for the first two items, I plan to add more items so the table will grow, but for now for testing purposes I have two lines so far.
[![
My second step is to allow inline editing for the QTY column which are two custom fields Item1__c and Item2__c. This is where I have hit a road block, I am not sure where in my code I would need to insert the line editable : true and also do the rest of the magic.][1]][1]
Please if someone can help me accomplish inline editing and if you have a better idea on how to display the data table in the record page and modify only the QTY column.

Comment: <!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<template>
    <h2> <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:orders" size="small"></lightning-icon> Kits</h2> 
    <!-- if:true will render the table only if data exist -->
    <template if:true={line1}> 
        <lightning-datatable 
            class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered"
            hide-checkbox-column="true"
            key-field="item"
            data={line1} 
            columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
</template>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the [lightning datatatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) component, which can be easily configured for inline editing of certain fields and other useful things.

**Update**

Here's the working code. Of course, you can [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record) right from the LWC, but I think it works slower if you want to update multiple records at once so I added a simple apex method.

**html**

```
<template>
  <!-- added this card div to make the container look more native to the whole page and have a background -->
  <div class="slds-card slds-p-around_medium">
    <h2>
      <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:orders" size="small"></lightning-icon>
      <span class="slds-m-left_small">Kits</span>
    </h2>
    <!-- added spinner to indicate that something is loading on load or save -->
    <lightning-spinner
      if:true={isLoading}
      variant="brand"
      size="medium"
    ></lightning-spinner>
    <!-- error will be displayed in red text here if something is wrong -->
    <div if:true={error} class="slds-text-color_error">{error}</div>
    <!-- table -->
    <div if:false={showTable}>Nothing to display</div>
    <template if:true={showTable}>
      <lightning-datatable
        class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered"
        hide-checkbox-column="true"
        key-field="Id"
        data={records}
        columns={columns}
        onsave={updateSelectedRecords}
      >
      </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

**js**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
// apex methods
import getRecords from "@salesforce/apex/DatatableWithSingleEditableFieldCtrl.getRecords";
import updateRecords from "@salesforce/apex/DatatableWithSingleEditableFieldCtrl.updateRecords";

// updated the fieldName fields to represent object's field api names
// because the datatable component will map its columns to record fields
const columns = [
  {
    label: "QTY #",
    fieldName: "Quantity__c",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: "true",
    sortable: false,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    label: "Item",
    fieldName: "Item__c",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: "true",
    sortable: false
  },
  {
    label: "Description",
    fieldName: "Description__c",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: "true",
    sortable: false
  },
  {
    label: "Serial",
    fieldName: "Serial__c",
    type: "text",
    hideDefaultActions: "true",
    sortable: false
  }
];

export default class DatatableWithSingleEditableField extends LightningElement {
  columns = columns;
  isLoading = true;

  error;
  records;

  @wire(getRecords, {})
  setRecords({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.records = data;
      this.toggleIsLoading();
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error.body.message;
    }
  }

  // added the getter instead of just checking for if:true={records}
  // because records will have a value of object event if there is nothing to show
  get showTable() {
    return this.records !== undefined && this.records.length > 0;
  }

  async updateSelectedRecords(event) {
    const draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
    try {
      this.toggleIsLoading();

      await updateRecords({ recordsJson: JSON.stringify(draftValues) });

      this.clearDraftValues();
      this.showSuccessMessage();
      this.toggleIsLoading();
    } catch (error) {
      this.showError(error);
    }
  }

  toggleIsLoading() {
    this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
  }

  // when you edit fields in datatable, it populates its draftValues property
  // and when all records successfully saved, draft values should be cleared
  // which automatically removes cancel and save buttons
  clearDraftValues() {
    const datatable = this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable");
    if (datatable) {
      datatable.draftValues = null;
    }
  }

  showError(error) {
    this.toggleIsLoading();
    this.error = error;
  }

  //   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation
  showSuccessMessage() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new ShowToastEvent({
        title: "Success",
        message: "Kits were successfully updated",
        variant: "success"
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**Apex controller class**
It's better to add best practices FLS checks and not put logic inside controller's methods as I did in this example.

```
public with sharing class DatatableWithSingleEditableFieldCtrl {
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static Kit__c[] getRecords() {
    try {
      return [
        SELECT Quantity__c, Item__c, Description__c, Serial__c
        FROM Kit__c
        WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
        LIMIT 10
      ];
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @AuraEnabled
  public static void updateRecords(String recordsJson) {
    try {
      List<Kit__c> kits = (List<Kit__c>) JSON.deserialize(
        recordsJson,
        List<Kit__c>.class
      );

      update kits;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**

[image: demo]

Comment: I have tried using a Lightning DataTable component first, but I was not able to display both the data that is coming from the custom object for the QTY column and at the same time displaying values that I manually want to display for the other columns.

Comment: I see. What does the quantity column mean? Is it a quantity of items or a position in the table?

Comment: QTY is the quantity of items that will be stored in a custom field.

Comment: Got it. I will create a different answer to this question with the full code for how to do it with the data table component

Comment: Thank you so much Anton, I really appreciate it

Comment: I was able to change the code to use Datatable like you suggested Anton. Now my issue is I am not able to display the value from the custom field. The only value I am able to feed is a manual string value.

Comment: @FrancoDD can you update the code in the question with the one you currently have?

Comment: I have updated the code but I was not able to properly add the HTML.

Comment: Can you send the html here in comment?

Comment: <template>
    <h2> <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:orders" size="small"></lightning-icon> Kits</h2> 
    <!-- if:true will render the table only if data exist -->
    <template if:true={line1}> 
        <lightning-datatable 
            class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered"
            hide-checkbox-column="true"
            key-field="item"
            data={line1} 
            columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
</template>

Comment: great, thanks. I will get back to you soon

Comment: @FrancoDD I populated the answer with working code

Comment: Incredible Anton, much appreciated. I will review it and get it to work. The only thing I noticed is that each record is each row, in my scenario one record will have multiple items. This is why I want to present the items in a table like format with its description and serial etc.